# Wordpress Images aren't showing on site (links OK though)

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Our website, http://www.goosedigital.com, is missing all of the images. Kind of.

When you view the website, no images appear, but when you click on the links in the source code, the images show fine. They're also showing in the CMS.

Any thoughts on what could have happened here? To my knowledge we haven't been in the website in weeks. However, we did pull down a sister site - which should have been unrelated but I have a suspicion it could be affecting this.

As an example, this code is in the banner. The image doesn't show, but the src works fine:

```
<div class="banner-image">
<img width="549" height="376" src="https://goosedigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner3.png" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="online marketing" srcset="http://goosedigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner3-300x205.png 300w, http://goosedigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner3.png 549w" sizes="(max-width: 549px) 100vw, 549px" draggable="true">                                    
</div>
```

Comment: You site uses https, images come from http.

Comment: Take a look at the console error _Mixed Content: The page at 'https://goosedigital.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://goosedigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner3.png'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS._ you should remove the schema from the images url and instead of serving it from `http://www...` it should be changed to `//www....` (without the **http** / **https** part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="banner-image">
<img width="549" height="376" src="https://goosedigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner3.png" 

class="attachment-full size-full" alt="online marketing" 
srcset="https://goosedigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner3-300x205.png 300w, https://goosedigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner3.png 549w" 
sizes="(max-width: 549px) 100vw, 549px" draggable="true">                                    
</div>
```

just change srcset protocol to https

Comment: Yessssss - Settings > General > change the WP / Site URLs.

Comment: This fixed the rest of the website, but images on the blog page are still having the same problem: [link](https://www.goosedigital.com/blog/)

Comment: you can solve this problem via edit posts they're must be https

Comment: Brad's comment below actually fixed the blog, but just the blog. Weird eh? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Read here;

http://www.barecode.co/wordpress-woocommerce-broken-images-since-update/

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', '__return_null' );
```

Comment: Although Onur's resolve fixed the overall website, this suggestion fixed the images on the blog page which weren't picking up the https srcset change. Thanks.

Comment: URL is broken. Be aware that this will remove `srcset` from your HTML, which may or may not be fine. In my case (old wordpress version, complex config) this is perfectly fine, and was the best way to fix persistent issues with mixed content warnings.